# Problem With the Rotation Edge CW

Tags: modeling

Like you see in the first photo below the edges rotated in this direction but in the cours im folowing they rotated in the opposive direction (see in photo 2). Could someone help me please.

Photo 1
[image: Photo one]
Photo 2
[image]

Comment: Just rotate again and again until it hits the correct rotation

Comment: Try Rotate Edge Clockwise or Counter clockwise command from likely Right click menu in Edge selection mode.. And from your question seems like course author did the same